# sum() returns incorrect value with join

Tags: mysql

Here i have tables

**1) users_interests**

```
user_id    interest_id
677        12
677        14
677        13
```

**2) answer_points**

```
user_id    in_id    point
677        12       -1
677        12       1
677        12       1
677        14       1
678        14       1
```

**3) interests**

```
id    name
12    movie
13    cooking
14    music
```

here what i want to do is,I want output like this

```
interest_id    name    point
12             movie   1
13             cooking 0
14             music   1
```

Where `user_id=677`

I tried this query

```
select ui.interest_id,i.name,sum(a.answer_points) as total from
users_interests as ui inner join interests as i on i.id=ui.interest_id
left join answer_points as a on a.in_id=ui.interest_id
where i.user_id='677' group by a.in_id
```

But its not counting `1` vote. it returns `3 total` for movie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for your requirement, Also check this below link

http://rextester.com/NQXE66482

```
SELECT 
J.interest_id AS 'ID',
I.NAME AS 'NAME',
CASE WHEN K.TOTAL != 0 THEN K.TOTAL
ELSE 0 END AS 'Total'
FROM
users_interests AS J
JOIN
interests AS I
ON
J.interest_id = I.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
 a.id AS 'ID', 
 a.name AS 'NAME', 
 SUM(b.point) as 'TOTAL'
 FROM 
 interests a 
 LEFT JOIN 
 answer_points b 
 ON a.id = b.in_id
 WHERE user_id = 677
 GROUP BY 1) AS K
 ON
J.interest_id = K.id
WHERE 
J.user_id = 677
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I have updated the code, It should work now. Basically you have to group by 1

Comment: I have added a Where statement so that it will take only the interests of User_id 677. Before that It was taking all 9 interests. Aama chali jase code

Comment: thanks bro. almost chale chhe. but to pan test kari lau hu. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select id,name,coalesce(find_in_set(id,in_id),0) as points 
from interests i 
left join(select distinct in_id 
from answer_points a where point = 1)a 
on a.in_id = i.id cross join users_interest u 
where u.user_id = 677 group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use left join starting for interests

```
select i.id, sum(a.point)
from interests as i 
left users_interests as ui on ui.interest_id = i.id
left join answer_points as a on a.user_id = ui.user_id and a.in_id = i.interest_id
where i.user_id=677
group by a.id
```

Comment: interests table has no interest_id and user_id. so i think have to correct some fields. can you post answer again?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change `JOIN` little like this,

```
select ui.interest_id, i.name, COALESCE(SUM(a.answer_points),0) as total from users_interests as ui
join interests as i on i.id = ui.interest_id
left join answer_points as a on a.in_id = ui.interest_id AND a.user_id = ui.user_id
where ui.user_id='677'
group by a.in_id
```

I had to compare `user_id` as well in `join` like this `AND a.user_id = ui.user_id`